# How can i add background music to my program?

Tags: java, audio, embedded-resource, javasound, background-music

I am attempting to add background music to my program but when i specify the path to the audio file i get the error message. How else can I specify this(this is going to be sent to another person). So the path cannot be on my system, it must be located in the JAR as well.

```
package main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;

public class Main extends JFrame {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main frame = new Main();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                PlaySound();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public static void PlaySound() {
    InputStream in;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(new File("/audio/Happy_Happy_Birthday.wav"));
        AudioStream audios = new AudioStream(in);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audios);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }

}

public Main() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 717, 508);
    contentPane = new JPanel() {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                    Main.class.getResource("/images/happy_birthday.jpg"));
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
        }
    };
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
}
}
```

Comment: /audio/Happy_Happy_Birthday has no extension, Are you sure its an audio file? it needs an extension.

Comment: My bad it was an error copying the code, i had the extension and still got the error

Comment: While not experienced with the Audio subsystem, I would be reluctant to play the audio within the same thread as the UI.

Answer (score 2):

- Load the clip using an `URL` rather than a `File`.   By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource).  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.
- Play the sound using a `javax.sound.sampled.Clip` (as opposed to undocumented classes in the `sun.audio` package).  See the [Java Sound info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for working source.

Answer (score -1):

```
InputStream in;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(new File("Jock_Jams_-_Are_You_Ready_For_This.wav"));
        AudioStream audios = new AudioStream(in);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audios);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }
```

I use this outside of my while loop and it works as long as if you don't mind it not being able to stop.